# Reference Files with CMake

Tags: cmake

is there a method to link specific files so that I can reference them inside my code?
I am developing a project where I'm reading in a video file from within my code and I want to reference it like:

```
const char* videopath = "myvideo.avi"
```

CMake usually builds inside a newly created directory so that the relative path is unknown to me. Current workaround is to reference the video file as an absolute path like:

```
videopath = "/home/NewProggie/Video/myvideo.avi"
```

I was wondering if there is a better way doing this, using CMake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [`CONFIGURE_FILE`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file)!

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
SET(MY_AVI_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/movies/foo.avi")
CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/avi.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/avi.h @ONLY)
```

In `avi.h.in`:

```
#pragma once
#define MY_AVI_PATH L"@MY_AVI_PATH@"
```

The result `avi.h`:

```
#pragma once
#define MY_AVI_PATH L"c:\foo\dir\movies\file.avi"
```